# Getting Error when trying to send mail to dynamic Email Id

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I have to develop one android send mail use javamailapi application.

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com,demo@mercuryminds.com"));
```

Using the above code mail is send to the recipient
But Now I wanted to send mail whose Id is written in the following String.

```
 string Email="mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com"
 message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("Email,demo@mercuryminds.com"));
```

When I use the above code mail is not getting send properly and it is giving me following error:

```
01-22 07:13:31.609: E/AndroidRuntime(959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 07:13:31.609: E/AndroidRuntime(959): java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
01-22 07:13:31.609: E/AndroidRuntime(959):   nested exception is:
01-22 07:13:31.609: E/AndroidRuntime(959):  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 553-5.1.2 We weren't able to find the recipient domain. Please check for any
01-22 07:13:31.609: E/AndroidRuntime(959): 553-5.1.2 spelling errors, and make sure you didn't enter any spaces, periods,
01-22 07:13:31.609: E/AndroidRuntime(959): 553 5.1.2 or other punctuation after the recipient's email address. ni8sm10202402pbc.70
```

please help me to solve my error and also how can i send the email ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("Email,demo@mercuryminds.com"));
```

with

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(Email+",demo@mercuryminds.com"));
```

Email address was not found because it was trying to find "Email" instead of value of Email("mercy.krishnaveni@gmail.com").

Hope that helps,